# python web app will not connect to database

Tags: python, sqlite, web, flask

I recently handed in my final project for CS50 as complete as I could. I spent nearly three days trying to debug this and couldn't get the program to work. Now I want to get this to work for my own personal satisfaction.

My issue is that the program, a Python/Flask website with a SQLite-based membership database and blog/nes functions that worked perfectly on the web site side of the project, but the database side would only run in limited capacity.

The database was established based on the parameters in my python code, but I cannot it populate either via the command line or the web form. I could populate the database using the SQLite GUI tool, so I know the database is correctly established.

When I try to put data in through the web interface I get no errors via http monitoring at the command line, and no data is posted to the database.

I am missing something, and am too close to see what is going on.

Help!

Here are the pertinent parts of the package as a whole:

**init**.py:

```
# Imports
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configyuration files
# Secret key
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '******************************'

# Database configuration
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db/site.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False # Stops overhead warning
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'join'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from application import routes
```

Forms.py:

```
# Imports
import os
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from application.models import User, Posts, News

# For to register users
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('Username', validators = [DataRequired()])
  email = StringField('Email', validators = [DataRequired(), Email()])
  password = PasswordField('Password', validators = [DataRequired()])
  confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators = [DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
  firstname = StringField('First name', validators = [DataRequired()])
  lastname = StringField('Last name', validators = [DataRequired()])
  street = StringField('Address 1', validators = [DataRequired()])
  address = StringField('Address 2')
  city = StringField('City', validators = [DataRequired()])
  state = StringField('State', validators = [DataRequired()])
  zipcode = StringField('Zip Code', validators = [DataRequired(), Length(min=5, max=10)])
  remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
  terms = BooleanField('Terms & Conditions')
  citizen = BooleanField('Citizen')
  submit = SubmitField('Submit')

  def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username = username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('We are sorry, that user name is already being used. Please choose another')

  def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email = email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('We are sorry, that email address is already being used. Please choose another')
```

models.py

```
# Imports
import os
from datetime import datetime
from application import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return  User.query.get(int(user_id))

# Database
# Members database
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False, default = 'default.jpeg')
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    street = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(20))
    city = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable = False)
    zipcode = db.Column(db.String(9), nullable = False)
    donates = db.Column(db.String())
    posts = db.relationship('Posts', backref = 'author', lazy = True)
    news = db.relationship('News', backref = 'contributor', lazy = True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.firstname}', '{self.lastname}', '{self.street}', '{self.address}', '{self.city}', '{self.state}', '{self.zipcode}',)"
```

routes.py:

```
# Membership, login/out, and account information
# Join the SBoR Project
@app.route('/join', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def join():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username = form.username.data, email = form.email.data, password = hashed_password, 
            firstname = form.firstname.data, lastname = form.firstname.data, 
            street = form.street.data, address = form.address.data, 
            city = form.city.data, state = form.state.data, zipcode = form.zipcode.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Thank you {form.firstname.data}, your account has been successfully created and you may now login.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    return render_template('join.html', title = 'Join', form = form)

# Signin to the SBoR Project
@app.route('/signin', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email = form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember = form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            flash(f'Login was unsuccessful, please check your email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('signin.html', title = 'Sign in', form = form)

# Logout from the SBoR Project
@app.route('/signout')
def signout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

This is what I get when I'm monitoring the http traffic in Powershell:

```
* Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2018 17:23:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2018 17:23:13] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2018 17:23:21] "GET /join HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2018 17:23:21] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2018 17:24:03] "POST /join HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2018 17:24:03] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

When I try to populate the database at the Python command line, I get this:

```
site.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'site' is not defined

db.session.add(username='username', firstname='First',    lastname='Last', email='person@mail.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

Here is the package tree:

```
application
├───db
│   └─── site.db
├───static
│   ├─── downloads
│   └─── profile_pics
├───templates
│   ├─── blog
│   ├─── constitution
│   ├─── errors
│   ├─── federalist
│   ├─── includes
│   ├─── news
│   ├─── policies
│   ├─── proposals
│   ├─── sbr
│   ├─── __init__.py
│   ├─── routes.py
│   ├─── forms.py
│   ├─── models.py
│   └─── 
└─── run.py
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Why are you trying to populate the db from the command line?. You've registered the database on the Flask App, there is no concept of that database, as db, outside of Flask

Comment: do you import db and site before call in command line?

Comment: Response 1: The app wont post any data to the database from the form. I tried to test it at the command line as part of my debugging routine to no avail. Response 2: Yes, I did import it at the command line while testing, but I cannot interact with the database. I keep getting errors (posted in examples).

Comment: If you haven't tried already, I'd add an `else:print(form.errors)` to the `if form.validate_on_submit()` to report any errors in the form.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I implemented it!